# Facebook Audience Network native Ads via Admob mediation adapter

Tags: android, facebook, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

So far I've been using Admob ads as well as facebook ads via admob mediation. I use the Facebook adapter from the list [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks#supported-ad-networks) to display banners and interstitials using only the admob api in my code. The adapter decides to display either facebook ads or admob without any further hassle from my side.

Now I am wondering whether the same thing can be achieved for native ads too. For example If I place a native ad somewhere in my app using admob code (e.g NativeExpressAdView). Will the FacebookAdapter be able to decide whether to display the native admob ad (which in this case is already implemented in code) OR the Facebook Native Ad? (which is not implemented in my code separately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my response from Admob mobile ads team.

> Mediation through FAN for Native Express Ads is currently not possible. Only Banner ads and Interstitials have been enabled for mediation for FAN.

Comment: Yep. While a lot of networks offer native ads, the Native Ads Express format itself is pretty unique to AdMob right now. It would be difficult to mediate other networks through it.